# Odoo 12 opens res.company form view instead of Qweb Report?

Tags: python-3.x, odoo-12, qweb

I create a Qweb Report that prints All products and their Movements during a specific period of time. i have checked  that all code and all functions,  everything is working very well.
The problem is that  odoo opens res.company form view unstead of printing the pdf report

Thanks for help.

Comment: if you are first time printing any qweb report odoo asking you to set layout. so when it open you have to first time choose layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MOHAMED

=>. The problem is that odoo opens res.company from view instead of printing the pdf report

**Solution** - you need to set the `company` the `logo`.if pop is raised and then try to print it will work.